# TikZ data visualization legends: reverse direction strategy or add empty entries?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, legend, tikz-datavisualization

I use the data visualization library of TikZ. I have a scatter plot with multiple sets. I have setup a preferred style sheet combination for the plot marks. These are ordered. I have also added legend texts. Now, because of the semantic meaning of the different sets, reflected in the legend text length, they are best grouped in a certain way. That grouping is incompatible with the plot mark order and any available legend direction strategy. It would be compatible with a reversed legend direction strategy. I could also fix it, if I could insert empty legend entries.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{datavisualization,plotmarks}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \datavisualization [
    scientific axes={inner ticks},
    x axis={
      attribute=x,
      label={meaning of $x$ axis},
      logarithmic,min value=10,max value=50000,
      ticks={minor steps between steps}
    },
    y axis={
      attribute=y,
      label={meaning of $y$ axis},
      min value=18.5,max value=29.5,
      ticks={minor steps between steps=1}
    },
    all axes=grid,
    visualize as scatter/.list={G,GF,simple,combined,new},
    legend={above,columns=2},
    % the following two should fill a column
    G={label in legend={text={a bit longer}}},
    GF={label in legend={text=short}},
    % the following three should fill another column
    simple={label in legend={text={quite a bit longer (simple, old)}}},
    combined={label in legend={text={quite a bit longer (combined, old)}}},
    new={label in legend={text={quite a bit longer (multiple)}}},
    style sheet=cross marks,
    style sheet=strong colors
  ]
    data [set=G] {
      x, y
      17513, 21.4
      1000 , 19.8
      2988 , 19.5
      30113, 28.9
      600  , 23.0
      31979, 21.2
    }
    data [set=GF] {
      x, y
      6000 , 27.4
    }
    data [set=simple] {
      x, y
      71   , 24.3
    }
    data [set=combined] {
      x, y
      40   , 22.6
    }
    data [set=new] {
      x, y
      180  , 21.6
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide the order of the legend entries or (better) a small sketch of the result you want to achieve?

Comment: @Excelsior: Can you tell me what can be improved about the comments in the minimal example?

Comment: I am not familar with this synthax. Do you need to draw it with datavisualization, or is an other methode also ok? I would define the labels of the legend entries an create a matrix for better alignment.

Comment: @Excelsior: I am looking for a datavisualization answer (or a indication that it is not possible). Others may be interested in solutions that fall outside datavisualization, so you are certainly free to provide your answer.